# How to run a PowerShell cmdlet in Python to get a list of connected USB devices?

Tags: python, powershell

I try to list connected USB devices in my Python project.

I tried to use `os.system()` with a command prompt but I cannot find a command for command prompt to list connected USB devices (names).

I found a PowerShell command which is

```
Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_. InstanceId -match '^USB' }
```

That works fine.

I want to know if there is either a command prompt to list USB connected devices with `os.system()` or how to run the PowerShell cmdlet in Python using `os.system()` or any other command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module called [pyUSB](https://pypi.org/project/pyusb/) that works really well.
Alternatively, to run Powershell commands, you can use the **subprocess** package.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", MyCommand], capture_output=True)
```

Comment: How can I format the output?

Answer (score 1):

My poor take at Python, I guess if you want to work with the output produced by PowerShell you might want to *serialize* the objects and *de-serialize* them in Python, hence the use of [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2).

```
import subprocess
import json

cmd = '''
    Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly |
        Where-Object { $_.InstanceId -match '^USB' } |
            ConvertTo-Json
'''

result = json.loads(
    subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True).stdout
)

padding = 0
properties = []

for i in result[0].keys():
    if i in ['CimClass', 'CimInstanceProperties', 'CimSystemProperties']:
        continue
    properties.append(i)
    if len(i) > padding:
        padding = len(i)

for i in result:
    for property in properties:
        print(property.ljust(padding), ':', i[property])
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.
In your case it will look like:

```
import subprocess

devices_raw: str = subprocess.run(
    ["Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_. InstanceId -match '^USB' }"],
    capture_output=True
).stdout

# ... working with devices_raw as a string, probably you'll need to split it or smth.
```

Comment: https://justpaste.it/1zfjd

Comment: Does it work when you run it in powershell?

Comment: Your `subprocess.run()` syntax is incorrect.