# Running Powershell script within Python

Tags: python, powershell

I have a Powershell script that is working and a Python script that is working. I would like to have the Python script run the powershell script for me. I am unable to download any packages because this is on a work computer.

I did look into this before asking and found/tried the following codes:

One:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(‘powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file “file location”’, stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Two:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.run(‘powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file “file location”’, shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

This seems to be the answer on every Reddit/SO question I’ve seen so I’m unsure why it doesn’t work for me. Does anyone know how to fix this? Or any work around?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem... please describe what exactly are you _expecting_ to happen, and then what _actually_ happens :)

Comment: I want the working Python Script I have to run the working Powershell script. When I run the code I have, nothing happens. It doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True)
```

On the cmd you can add what ever command you would like to run.
Im currently working on a project that includes powershell script running via python and this method works fine for me.
One problem though:
If you declare this as a variable and you want to iterate through the output,
it creates a list of chrs instead of lines(probably easy fix but I didnt have the time to think about a solution).

Comment: You can always serialize the output from the PowerShell command and de-serialize it in Python (my Python is awful but you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72335974/15339544))